# Can't access the sms gateway from spring resttemplate

Tags: java, spring, rest, resttemplate

I have sms gateway which I can give url and send sms which is shown below.

"https://url/destination={mobileNum}&q=mypw\n&message={msg}\n"

I have used that in resttemplate and trying to send the sms but it didn't work.

```
public String send(String mobileNumber, String message) {

    String uri = "https://url/destination={mobileNum}&q=mypw\n&message={msg}\n";
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    URI result = restTemplate.postForLocation(uri, mobileNumber, message);


    return result.toString();
    //return null;
}
```

Other parts of the code is working fine. It does not give any errors. But sms sending part is not working. How can I fix the problem?

Comment: show the response part as well..What you receive from the sms gateway webservice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess problem in `new-line` character which you are using in URL. Try to escape `\`

Another problem with URL in using of queryParams. Query params should be after `?` delimeter.

So final URL can looks like:

```
String uri = "https://url?destination={mobileNum}&q=mypw\\n&message={msg}\\n";
```

[The components of a URL](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGMCP_5.3.0/com.ibm.cics.ts.internet.doc/topics/dfhtl_uricomp.html)

Comment: @SanduniWickramasinghe It hard to say more without response from server and specification for SMS gateway, but try to change `postForLocation` on  `postForEntity` and output response.

Comment: SMS gateway works fine when I just type it on browser search bar, sms is sent to my phone

Comment: when chaged to postForEntity parameter become incompatible

Comment: there is no problem with the url. I want to know errors in the code only

Comment: Could you please show response from server? It hard to say more without context

Comment: > when chaged to postForEntity parameter become incompatible
What becomes incompatible? what kind errors do you faced with?

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
public String send(String mobileNumber, String message) {

String uri = "https://url/destination=" mobileNumber + "&q=mypw&message="+message;
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

String result = restTemplate.getForObject(uri, String.class);
return result;
```

}

As per the RestTemplate docs the method postForLocation is used to create a new resource by POSTing the given object to the URI template, and returns the value of the Location header. This header typically indicates where the new resource is stored. [RestTemplate docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#postForLocation-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object...-)

The server might not allowing to query the location of the new resource and hence will not send the location header in response.

Comment: By this method how can I give mobileNumber and message?. sms can not send without mobileNumber

Comment: if that is in the url then construct the url by adding the mobileNumber and message

Comment: it changes from time to time. Taken from user

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152729/discussion-between-sangam-belose-and-sanduni-wickramasinghe).

Answer (score 0):

There was an error reading the URL. "mypw&message" was taken as the password instead of just "mypw". I found it while debugging the code using jboss debug mode.

This is the final code

```
@Service
public class SmsServiceImpl implements SmsService{

@Override
public String send(String mobileNumber, String message) {
    String uri = "https://urlTodestination="+mobileNumber+"&q=pw&message="+message;

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    String result = restTemplate.getForObject(uri,  String.class);

    return result;
}
```

}